# How do I specify a different mapping to use for html arguments with html2latex?

Tags: html

html2latex seems to replace all `<hr>` elements with `\hline`, which isn't quite the right mapping.

How do I go about changing this mapping to a more appropriate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the [version of html2latex](http://html2latex.sourceforge.net/) I was using, ignored the configuration file command line argument. I manually fixed the file, and solved my problem.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "outdated html2latex repo"?  specifically, where is there anything better?

Comment: @wasteofspace google showed me dozens of attempts by others to create better versions, with various fixes and improvements. that said, seems the 2000 repo is still the standard source for html2latex, so I changed my wording.